# Get children count in linq to entities query

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I have a many to many relation between two tables in my database (MySql) :

- Category (id, name, id_parent)
- Sound (id, name)

A category ***can*** have 1 parent category, so a category ***can*** have many children. If a category has at least one child, it has no sounds in it. I do not allow sounds and children categories together.

So for a parent category, i want to get all children that may have children that may have children (...) and i want to count sounds in all children recursively.

Exemple :

Cat -> (CCat1 -> CCCat11(2 sounds), CCat2 (5 sounds), CCat3 -> CCat31 -> CCCat311 -> (CCCCat3111 (10 sounds), CCCCat3111 (1 sound))

There is no deep limit, that's why i need a "recursively" way to count sounds.

- Cat has 3 children.
- CCat1 has 1 child.
- CCat2 has no child.
- CCat3 has 1 child that has 1 child that has 2 children.

Cat.nbSounds = 18

Comment: If you are getting this information from a database you should try to make a stored procedure. Otherwise you would have to send tons of information to the client, with a stored procedure you only have to send the final number.

Comment: @MrFox: If you can create a LINQ query that returns this data, you are not sending "tons of information to the client".

Comment: I have a feeling a single LINQ query won't cut it in this case. My first idea is to write a recursive method to look for child categories and return the counts from them... But that in turn is a lot of queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more researches it seems that we can't do what i want.

So i created a recursive method that retrieve children and calculate the number of sounds in each category (i count sounds in the category or i count categories children number of sounds).

If you find a magical way to do it anyway with linq to entities, i take it !

Answer (score 4):

The answer lies in the user of the `SelectMany` operator.

```
int count_soundsinparent = parentCategory
    .Select(x=> x.ChildCategory)
    .SelectMany(x=> x.Sounds)
    .Count();
```

Suppose you would've used a regular `Select`; it would return you a list (one item per child category) of a list of sounds (one item per sound the child category has), thus creating a two-dimensional list.

What `SelectMany` does is take all the elements of that list, and put it in a one dimensional list. Then you count the items in that list and voila, you have the total.

Comment: I can't try this because i need to get all children before, so i edited my post :)

Comment: and are you sure that with this request i get all sounds count ? Because in childcategory i can have children in too

Comment: Yeah I noticed too late. This only works if you only have 1 level of descendants. You can fix it with a recursive function though. Let me get back to you on that :)

Answer (score 1):

> recursively

This requirement means you're not going to do it in a single LINQ query. Linq can't really express a recursive query with linq to *objects*, let alone a more comlex provider such as Linq to Entities.

With the schema you describe, you'd be better off writing a stored procedure. If you had a nested sets model, you *might* be able to do some mathematical manipulation of left edge and right edge numbers, but probably not with those extra rules.